# CountifS + multiple criteria + distinct count

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, distinct

I'm looking for a formula calculating : distinct Count + multiple criteria
Countifs() does it but do not includes distinct count...

Here is an example.

I have a table on which I want to count the number of distinct items (column item) satisfying multiple conditions one column A and B : A>2 and B<5.

[Image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvwX5.jpg)

[image]

```
Line  Item  ColA  ColB
1     QQQ    3     4
2     QQQ    3     3
3     QQQ    5     4
4     TTT    4     4
5     TTT    2     3
6     TTT    0     1
7     XXX    1     2
8     XXX    5     3
9     zzz    1     9
```

Countifs works this way : COUNTIFS([ColumnA], criteria A,   [ColumnB], criteria B)

COUNTIFS([ColumnA], > 2 ,   [ColumnB], < 5)

Returns : lines 1,2,4,5,8 => Count = 5

**How can I add a distinct count function based on the Item Column ?** :

lines 1,2 are on a unique item QQQ

lines 4,5 are on a unique item TTT

Line 8 is on a unique item XXX

Returns Count = 3

How can I count 3 ?!

Thanks

You can download the excel file @ [Excel file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qsl0y8k47v2ssei/stackoverflow.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Looks like you edited to add "zzz", so your final count should still be 3? or 4?

Comment: Yes, I added a ZZZ to make obvious that the wanted result (3) is not just the number of items, it's the number of distinct items satisfying the constraints on columns A and B,

Answer (score 10):

Newer versions of Excel allow for this problem to be solved in a (relatively) more simple way.  It certainly is easier to follow and understand, conceptually.

First, filter the table based on multiple criteria (join multiple with the *):

```
=FILTER(Table,(Table[Column A]>2)*(Table[Column B]<5))
```

[image: screenshot1]

Then, grab the "Item" column with INDEX:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(Table,(Table[Column A]>2)*(Table[Column B]<5)),,2)
```

[image: screenshot2]

Next, filter for unique entries:

```
=UNIQUE(INDEX(FILTER(Table,(Table[Column A]>2)*(Table[Column B]<5)),,2))
```

[image: screenshot3]

Finally, perform a count:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(INDEX(FILTER(Table,(Table[Column A]>2)*(Table[Column B]<5)),,2)))
```

[image: screenshot4]

Comment: This is a superior answer. Really well explained.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I found one issue; when the filter function returns no results we get a `#calc` error which `counta` then counts, so we get 1 instead of 0.  The fix seems to be this: `SUM(--(LEN(UNIQUE(IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(Table,(Table[Column A]>2)*(Table[Column B]<5)),,2),"")))>0))`; thanks to a trick explained here: https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-values

Answer (score 6):

Ugly formula, but it works.

```
=SUM(((FREQUENCY(IF(C2:C10>2,1,0)*IF(D2:D10<5,1,0)*(COUNTIF(B2:B10,">"&B2:B10)+1),ROW(B2:B10)-ROW(B2)))*(ROW(B2:B11)-ROW(B2))>0)*1)
```

I'll start with the criteria IFS:

```
IF(C2:C10>2,1,0)*IF(D2:D10<5,1,0)
```

Gives an array of 1s and 0s for the rows that satisfy both criteria. ARRAY = {1;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;0} for your example.

Where B2:B10 is the Item column, the countif formula:

```
COUNTIF(B2:B10,">"&B2:B10)
```

returns {6;6;6;3;3;3;1;1;0} where the number equals the number of item values in B2:B10 alphabetically less than the tested item value.

- QQQ goes to 6 [3"TTT", 2"XXX", 1"zzz"]
- TTT goes to 3 [2"XXX", 1"zzz"]
- XXX goes to 1 [1"zzz"]
- zzz goes to 0 [0 less than "zzz"]

Need to add 1 to this array to make sure there are no 0 values:
{7;7;7;4;4;4;2;2;1}.

So when multiplying the criteria, and the countif statement:

```
IF(C2:C10>2,1,0)*IF(D2:D10<5,1,0)*(COUNTIF(B2:B10,">"&B2:B10)+1)
```

You get ARRAY = {7;7;7;4;0;0;0;2;0}.

```
FREQUENCY(ARRAY,ROW(B2:B10)-ROW(B2))
```

ROW(B2:B10)-ROW(B2) sets the frequency bins to {0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8}. So the output of the frequency formula is {4;0;1;0;1;0;0;3;0;0} where the last 0 is for all values greater than 8.

((ROW(B2:B11)-ROW(B2)>0)*1) equals {0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1}. Multiplying ARRAY by this removes the 0 count at the start: ARRAY = {0;0;1;0;1;0;0;3;0;0}. [NOTE: B11 is lowest item column cell+1 because of the added array value from the frequency formula for values over 8]

(ARRAY)>0)*1 = {0;0;1;0;1;0;0;1;0;0}

SUM this = 3.

ctrl + shift + enter, because it's an array formula.

cmd + shift + enter for mac.

Comment: This is the best thing I've seen on the internet since MSN messenger was a thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

`=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(B2:B10,B2:B10))`

Credit where credit due, however ... I found it over here:

https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-values-in-a-range-with-countif

Comment: It does not correspond to the subject.
It counts the "Count unique values in a range", using CountIF as a tool.
But it's not a Countif with distinct count.

Comment: What?  It gives the results you want, it uses CountIf ... trying to read more into than that is playing with semantics.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding iferror at filter or index stage to

`=COUNTA(UNIQUE(INDEX(FILTER(Table,(Table[Column A]>2)*(Table[Column B]<5)),,2)))`

`=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(TableABC, (TableABC[ID]=xxx)*(TableABC[Date]=ddd)),,2), "")`