# Get unique count with two conditions in excel

Tags: excel, count

How to get the count of unique keys with two conditions.
Ex. Room C3 dated 2/1

Answer : 2 
Since 123 and 124 is only the unique keys under C3 and 2/1

```
Keys Room. Dates
123  C1    2/1
125  C1    2/4
124  C3    2/2
123  C3    2/1
124  C3    2/1
123  C3    2/1
```

Comment: Look into `COUNTIFS`

Comment: did you try googling something like [excel count multiple criteria](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+count+multiple+criteria&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS821US821&oq=excel+count+multiple&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.3983j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)? Tons of answers that negate the need for this question.

Comment: Sorry @cybernetic.nomad and Scott Holtzmann, but Countifs does not cut it for this. It will not return a unique count.

Comment: @teylyn, you need to combine countifs with sumproduct.

Comment: @user11138753 I know that. I'm just saying that it can't be done with just Countifs, as the comments seem to imply.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman there were no given formula to get the unique values.

Answer (score 0):

With Excel a unique count has always been a challenge. Approaches involve either long, convoluted array formulas (see [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4091-excel-count-unique-values-based-on-multiple-criteria.html) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992116/countifs-multiple-criteria-distinct-count) ) or using Pivot tables as an intermediate step.

With the new Dynamic Array functions currently in preview for Office 365 Insider builds, this is a piece of cake, though.

This formula entered into just one single cell, no copying, will filter the data to return only the unique rows:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(B4:D9,(C4:C9=G2)*(D4:D9=G3),""))
```

The screenshot shows that the data automatically "spills" into the rows below.

[image]

If you are only interested in the final count, then filter only the first column and count the resulting data in one formula:

```
=COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(B4:B9,(C4:C9=G2)*(D4:D9=G3),"")))
```

[image]

Comment: As I write in my answer, it requires the Office 365 Insider build which has the new dynamic array formulas. It does not work in other versions of Excel.